# How to obtain single unique list of items given an list of lists

Tags: kotlin

Given the following models:

```
class Participant {
   var email = ""
}

class Reservation {
   var participants = ArrayList<Participant>()
}

val reservations = ArrayList<Reservation>()
```

How can I get a unique list of emails in `reservations`, but only if the email is not blank ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
reservations.flatMap { reservation -> reservation.participants }
            .distinctBy { participant -> participant.email }
            .map { participant -> participant.email }
            .filter { email -> email.isNotBlank() }
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Or like this:

```
reservations.flatMap { 
    it.participants.map(Participant::email).filter(String::isNotBlank)
}.toSet() // or .distinct()
```

Since each element should be unique you might want to use a `Set`, if you just want a unique List use `distinct()` at the end.